# Split PDF in separate file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation

i Have a big pdf file and i would like to split it in separate PDF files, each page in separate file.

It is possible to do that in JS with node module.

I search but in npm i just have modules that convert html to pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of searching and nearly giving up, I did eventually find that the HummusJS library will do what I want to do! thanks to @Taxilian

See this post [How can I create a customized version of an existing pdf file with node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259422/how-can-i-create-a-customized-version-of-an-existing-pdf-file-with-node-js?rq=1)

Comment: nice. Another nodejs wrapper around good library. All of them can solve you problem

Comment: appears it does wrap the HummusPDF "executable" as it were.  See also pdfkit.

Comment: It seems HummusJS ending support . Is there any good alternative ?

Comment: https://github.com/jjwilly16/node-pdftk this may be the potential alternative to split pages

Answer (score 3):

PDF format too complex for handling it via javascript. Can't find any js libs, that doing it well

It's easy to use other pdf parsing software and run it from node.js

use [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) for splitting pdf

`pdftk input.pdf burst output output_%02d.pdf`

and run it via `child-process`

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('pdftk input.pdf burst output output_%02d.pdf',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

[pdftk split pdf with multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991144/pdftk-split-pdf-with-multiple-pages)

maybe you can find node module for using pdftk, but it's too easy to run it by yourself

Comment: Thanks for your answer but check what i found!

Comment: There's also a great library called [scissors](https://github.com/tcr/scissors) that wraps pdftk for Node.js - imo much easier to use than HummusJS but either should work.