# Is it possible to split a PDF file into multiple pages using javascript at the client side

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a use case where users can upload a multi page PDF file. 
I want to show preview of each page separately at the time of uploading. One way to it that I can send the file to server and split and send it back to client side for preview but I don't want to do that.

Is there a way to split the PDF at the client side using JavaScript(no server API calls).

If Yes then how and if no then why it is not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split PDF in seperate file in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039152/split-pdf-in-seperate-file-in-javascript)

Comment: @AdnanUmer in link you provided, the splitting process is done at server side via node.js, here this guy asks for client side method.

Comment: By using HTML5 and some sort of javascript library which can handle PDF in browser maybe possible. If you have time, check this library https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: Did you find any solution?